# Imported Module Issue

Tags: shell, powershell, module, account

I downloaded and import a module called LocalAccount.

I had an issue with importing it, but the solution was to delete the **psd1** from the Module's folder to get it to work and it did work. I managed to import it.

Now, when I try to run any command from the Module and I receive this error:

```
Cannot find an appropriate constructor to instantiate the custom attribute object for type 'Alias'.
```

I tried to copy the **psd1** file back, but it did not solve the issue.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: "I had an issue with importing it" - please describe said issue - was there any errors? If so, please post them

Comment: I have not seen that before. Every function in the `LocalAccount.psm1` file has this added `[Alias()]`. Looks like an empty constructor to me, but it may be harmless.. I don't knw. Try commenting those out and see what happens